# Mysql creating 1 table to be used for multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database, schema

I currently have made tables **Person, branch, and clients**. They all need to have data for where they are located.

My question is can I have **1 locations table for all three tables** and locationid will auto_increment or should I create **Location table for each one; person_location, branch_location, and client_location**? Maybe I could add all the columns within each table Person, Branch, and Clients instead in a separate table.

Comment: Does the Person, branch, clients share the same location?

Comment: no persons, branchs, and clients don't share the same location.

Comment: If person, branch, clients's location don't have relationship, then you can create a one location table, then another table specifying the location type (i.e. id 1 for person, 2 for branch, 3 for client)

Answer (score 0):

no u dont need to create location table for each other tables.just make one table location..

but in other table add an column locationid which will hold the location id from location table.

thus u can get the location in each table.